# Cordovaで電話やメールをするには

Tags: cordova

動作してほしい環境はAndroidとiOSです。

電話やメールのアイコンをタップした時に、外部のアプリケーション（OSの標準の電話やメーラーを想定）を起動して発信したいですがどのようにやればいいでしょうか。

```
<a href="tel:00000000000">
```

と言ったやり方や、いろんなプラグインが散見されましたが、プラグインのインストールの仕方や使い方がわからなかったり、iOSでのみ動作しなかったりでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

解決した手順をまとめます。

1. プラグインのインストール(特に設定はいじらなくてよかった)

   cordova plugins add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
2. jsで

   window.open("tel:00011112222", "_system")
   window.open("mailto:aaa@example.com")

備考

- iOSシミュレータでは動作しませんが、実機では動作しました。
- genymotionのAndroidシミュレータでは、動作しました。
- window.openではなくでやると動作しなかった
- "_system"でなく、"_blank"だと、正しく動作しなかった

参考リンク
* http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
* http://blog.innobase.co.jp/entry/2014/11/06/203746

Answer (score 0):

InAppBrowserを使用する方法があるようですが、これは既に確認されているものとして、iOSで動かないとのことですが、シミュレーターでしょうか？

TELなど一部機能は実機に転送して確認しないと動作しないようですので、実機デバッグで確認してみてはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。
InAppBrowserをインストールし、
  window.open("tel:00012345678", "_system")
とした場合、
仰るとおり、シミュレータだと動きませんでしたが、実機では動きました。